MoviePy write_videofile is extremely slow
So I have am using MoviePy's concatenate_videoclips function to combine two video clips that have a image and some text overlayed on each of them. When I write the video file it takes around a WHOLE 2 minutes to complete. When I scaled it up with around 100 clips with the same info (a image and some text overlayed) it takes up to around 4 hours for just a 15 minute video. I am wondering if there is a way to mitigate this time. Is MoviePy not suited for something like this?
My example is this which runs at around 4it/s with both videos being at 1920x1080 and are both 10 secconds:
from moviepy.editor import *
from moviepy.config import change_settings

change_settings({"IMAGEMAGICK_BINARY": "D:\\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI\\magick.exe"})

def create(vid_path: str) -> CompositeVideoClip:
    vid: VideoFileClip = VideoFileClip(vid_path)
    vid = vid.crossfadein(0.8)
    vid = vid.crossfadeout(0.8)

    name_square: ImageClip = ImageClip(".\\square.png")
    name_square = name_square.set_position(('center', 856))
    name_square = name_square.set_duration(vid.duration)
    name_square = name_square.crossfadein(1)
    name_square = name_square.crossfadeout(1)

    name_text: TextClip = TextClip(txt="Hello", fontsize=90, color="gray", font="MomCake")
    name_text = name_text.set_position(("center", 870))
    name_text = name_text.set_duration(vid.duration)
    name_text = name_text.crossfadein(1)
    name_text = name_text.crossfadeout(1)

    comp_clip: CompositeVideoClip = CompositeVideoClip([vid, name_text])
    return comp_clip

final: VideoFileClip = concatenate_videoclips([create("vid1.mp4"), create("vid2.mp4")])
final.write_videofile(f"final_vid.mp4", threads=12, preset="ultrafast", ffmpeg_params=['-b:v','10000k'])

My PC's specs are:
Intel i7-9700K
32GB of memory
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
They seem like they should be more than enough for a job like this. It also seems that MoviePy doesn't utilize my GPU and puts all the video encoding on the CPU.
I use as many of MoviePy's ffmpeg functions as possible to speed things up but the write_videofile function is still very slow. I tried all optimizations I could find but none made a difference. With some of them I can get the iteration per seconds to go up by a significant amount but after a few seconds of processing, that number falls off a cliff and goes back to 3-5it/s. Some of the optimizations I've tried are:
threads=12
preset="ultrafast"
audio=False
logger=False
ffmpeg_params=['-b:v','10000k']
